# k8s deploy minio,but web console page cannot be accessed

Tags: azure, kubernetes, minio

k8s file like this from bitnami

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  labels:
    app: minio
  name: minio
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: minio
  serviceName: minio
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: minio
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: BITNAMI_DEBUG
          value: "false"
        - name: MINIO_SCHEME
          value: http
        - name: MINIO_FORCE_NEW_KEYS
          value: "no"
        - name: MINIO_ROOT_USER
          value: linkflow
        - name: MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: Sjtu403c@#%
        - name: MINIO_BROWSER
          value: "on"
        - name: MINIO_PROMETHEUS_AUTH_TYPE
          value: public
        - name: MINIO_CONSOLE_PORT_NUMBER
          value: "9001"
        image: registry.aliyuncs.com/linkflow/minio-bitnami
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 5
          httpGet:
            path: /minio/health/live
            port: minio-api
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 5
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        name: minio
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
          name: minio-api
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9001
          name: minio-console
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 5
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 5
          successThreshold: 1
          tcpSocket:
            port: minio-api
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 1Gi
          requests:
            memory: 1G
        securityContext:
          runAsNonRoot: true
          runAsUser: 1001
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /data
          name: data
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1001
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    metadata:
      name: data
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 20Gi
      storageClassName: default
      volumeMode: Filesystem
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: minio
  name: minio
spec:
  ports:
  - name: minio-api
    port: 9000
    targetPort: minio-api
  - name: minio-console
    port: 9001
    targetPort: minio-console
  selector:
    app: minio
```

when i use local k8s portforward ,it run ok. get http://127.0.0.1/minio web console is can be see

```
kubectl port-forward svc/minio 9001:9001
```

my ingress

```
      - backend:
          service:
            name: minio
            port:
              number: 9001
        path: /minio
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

and when i use azure SLB with domain, https://hostname/minio it error
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

i try add env MINIO_BROWSER_REDIRECT_URL,but not work. how could i do?

Answer (score 1):

ingress patch need to change to /

```
 - backend:
          service:
            name: minio
            port:
              number: 9001
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```